# With angus-activation 1.0 (Jakarta Activation 2.x) where exactly is the API implementation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to migrate jakarta.activation from com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation (contains both API implementation and com.sun.registries/) to the "official" Eclipse angus-activation.

How is this supposed to work exactly? When I replace the jar with angus-activation 1.0.0 there is the registries implementation
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-activation/tree/master/activation-registry

...but... there doesn't seem to be an API implementation. I understand that we should **NOT** include jakarta.activation-api artifact as that is compile only.

angus-activation here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/angus-activation

Oracle's implementaton: jakarta.activation here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation

The Oracle jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar contains more classes than Eclipse angus-activation-1.0.0.jar.

The compile-time artifact here:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api